# class.FaviconFinder.php - add more validation

Tags: php

This is a second rev of this [SE Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95246/favicon-downloading-script).

How can I add more validation to this .ico file downloader?

It works but I need a way to check the integrity of each step:

- Check Default location ( checked length is greater than 20 ) ( broken
  for test.com ... why ?
- Check Google API ( validation already added )
- Scrape page for ico location and download directly ( last resort )

And of course general feedback.  Note I Use a GET request to test the script invoking debug.

```
<?php

if($_GET)
{
    $obj = new FaviconFinder();
    $obj->invokeDebug($_GET);
}

class FaviconFinder
{
    // domain before and after redirects
    private $domain;
    private $real_domain;

    // the domain and how it was obtained
    private $domain_code = '0';
    private $domain_file;

    // the favicon and how it was obtained
    private $favicon_code = 'z';
    private $favicon_file;
    private $ext;

    // paths local to server and on the internet (URL)
    private $path_local_server = "../../favicons/";
    private $name_db;
    private $path_internet;

/****************************************************************************************************
* invoke
****************************************************************************************************/

    public function invoke( $pipe )
    {
        $domain = $pipe['domain'];
        $this->domain = $domain;
        if ( $this->googleAPIFound($domain) )
        {
            $pipe = $this->saveFavicon($pipe, true);
            $pipe['favicon'] = 'NULL';
            $pipe['favicon_local'] = $this->name_db;
        } else if ( $this->defaultFound($domain) )
        {
            $pipe = $this->saveFavicon($pipe, true);
            $pipe['favicon'] = 'NULL';
            $pipe['favicon_local'] = $this->name_db;
        } else if ( $this->pageFound($domain) && $this->linkFound() && $this->getFavicon($this->path_internet) )
        {
            $pipe = $this->saveFavicon($pipe);
            $pipe['favicon'] = $this->path_internet;
            $pipe['favicon_local'] = $this->name_db;
        } else {
            $pipe['favicon'] = 'NULL';
            $pipe['favicon_local'] = 'image_generic.png';
        }
        $pipe['method'] = $this->domain_code . $this->favicon_code;
        return $pipe;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* defaultFound
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function defaultFound ($domain) {
        $default_location = 'http://www.' . $domain . '/favicon.ico';
        if( $this->getFavicon( $default_location) )
        {
            $this->domain_code = 'default - 1';
            $this->path_internet = $default_location;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* googleAPIFound
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function googleAPIFound ($domain) {
        $favicon = @file_get_contents('https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=' . $domain);

        // remove this
        $favicon64 = base64_encode($favicon);
        if ( hash('md5', $favicon64) == '99fd8ddc4311471625e5756986002b6b' ) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $this->domain_code = 'google - 1';
            $this->favicon_file = $favicon;
            return true;
        }
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* pageFound
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function pageFound ($domain) 
    {
        return $this->pageFoundGet($domain) || $this->pageFoundCurl($domain);
    }
    private function pageFoundCurl ($domain)
    {
        $types = array(
            "curl - 1"=>$domain, 
            "curl - 2"=>'www.' . $domain,
            "curl - 4"=>'https://www.' . $domain, 
            "curl - 3"=>'http://www.' . $domain,
            "curl - 6"=>'https://' . $domain,
            "curl - 5"=>'http://' . $domain
        );

        foreach ($types as $key => $value) {
            $this->domain_file = $this->curlExec($value, true);
            if ($this->domain_file)
            {
                $this->domain_code = $key;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private function pageFoundGet( $domain )
    {
        $types = array(
            "file_get - 1"=>$domain, 
            "file_get - 2"=>'www.' . $domain,
            "file_get - 3"=>'http://www.' . $domain,
            "file_get - 4"=>'https://www.' . $domain, 
            "file_get - 5"=>'http://' . $domain,
            "file_get - 6"=>'https://' . $domain
        );

        foreach ($types as $key => $value) {
            if ($this->domain_file = $this->fileGetContents( $value ))
            {
                $this->domain_code = $key;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* linkFound
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function linkFound()
    {
        $domain = $this->real_domain;
        $regex = '#<link\s+(?=[^>]*rel=(?:\'|")(?:shortcut\s)?icon(?:\'|")\s*)(?:[^>]*href=(?:\'|")(.+?)(?:\'|")).*>#i';
        $link_found = preg_match( $regex , $this->domain_file, $matches );
        if($link_found === 1)
        {
            $path = $matches[1];
            if ( $path[0] === '/' && $path[1] === '/' )
            {
                $this->favicon_code = 'a';
                $this->path_internet = 'http:' . $path;
            }
            else if( $path[0] === '/' )
            {
                $this->favicon_code = 'b';
                $this->path_internet = 'http://www.' . $domain . $path;
            }
            else if ( substr($path, 0, 4) === 'http' )
            {
                $this->favicon_code = 'c';
                $this->path_internet = $path;
            }
            else
            {
                $this->favicon_code = 'd';
                $this->path_internet = 'http://www.' . $domain . '/' . $path;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* getFavicon
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function getFavicon($url)
    {
        return $this->getFaviconCurl($url) ;  
    }
    private function getFaviconCurl($url)
    {
        $temp = $this->curlExec( $url, false );
        if($temp === false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(strlen($temp) < 20) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        $this->favicon_file = $temp;
        return true;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* saveFavicon
****************************************************************************************************/

    public function saveFavicon( $pipe, $switch )
    {
        if ($switch) {
            $this->ext = "ico";
        } else {
            $arr = parse_url($this->path_internet);
            $this->ext = pathinfo($arr['path'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }
        $name = str_replace('.', '_', $this->domain);
        if ($this->ext) {
            $name = $name . "." . $this->ext;
        }
        file_put_contents($this->path_local_server . $name, $this->favicon_file);
        $this->name_db = $name;
        return $pipe;
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* wrapper functions 
****************************************************************************************************/

    private function curlExec ($url, $set)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        ));
        $temp = curl_exec($curl);
        if ($set) {
            $url = curl_getinfo( $curl )['url'];
            $url = parse_url($url);
            $url = $url['host'];
            $this->real_domain = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $url);        
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        return $temp;
    }
    private function fileGetContents ($value)
    {
        $opts = array(
            'http'=>array(
                'follow_location' => true,
                'max_redirects' => 20
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        return @file_get_contents( $value, false, $context );
    }

/****************************************************************************************************
* invokeDebug
****************************************************************************************************/

    public function invokeDebug($pipe)
    {

        if ($pipe['domain'])
        {
            $pipe = $this->invoke($pipe);
            echo "<br> domain              | " . $pipe['domain'] . "";
            echo "<br> domain_code         | " . $this->domain_code;
            echo "<br> favicon_code        | " . $this->favicon_code;
        }
        if ($this->favicon_file)
        {
            echo "<br> favicon_file type   | " . gettype($this->favicon_file);
            echo "<br> favicon_file length | " . strlen($this->favicon_file);
            echo "<br> favicon_file        | " . $this->favicon_file;

            $file64 = base64_encode($this->favicon_file);
            echo "<br> <img src= 'data:image/" . $this->ext . ";base64," . $file64 . "'></img>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tim has rolled back the last edit, because it invalidates the given answers. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full review, just a couple of things I noticed.

**Security: XSS**

You definitely want to fix the XSS vulnerability. The most obvious one is where you echo `$pipe['domain']`, where `$pipe` is just `$_GET`. It's difficult to grasp if the other values, such as `favicon_file` might possibly contain payloads as well, so just to be sure, I would encode them as well.

**Security: Code Execution**

It's a bit unclear what exactly `favicon_file` might be. But in `saveFavicon`, you use the original file extension, instead of using `.ico` or at least checking the extension. So if an attacker managed to set `favicon_file` to something like `favicon.php`, you may be vulnerable.

It seems that this is currently a problem with the `linkFound` function, which seems to take any file, regardless of extension, from a remote server. You would also need to trust that plus.google.com only returns .ico files, and that all future icon finder functions only return icons.

**Functions**

I find your function signatures somewhat confusing. For example, `saveFavicon` accepts `$pipe`, doesn't do anything with it, and then returns it.

It also has a `$switch` value which is very unclear. Generally, boolean values are not ideal as they make functions harder to use. And what is switched?

The arguments for `invoke` are also not that clear to me. It accepts `$pipe` and then sets a whole bunch of values in this array, and returns it. So it seems that it's purpose is to set values in `$pipe`. But really, it's main functionality seems to be the side-effect of downloading the favicon. Most of the set values are also not used (at least in your example).

**Structure and Classes**

First of, your class does a bit too much for my taste. It searches favicons (via multiple very different methods), it downloads them, and it saves them. Each could be handled by a different class.

What you want to do is save a favicon via X methods. Your invoke code is a bit hard to read though. I would probably create a `FaviconFinder` interface (with methods such as `findFavicon` or `getFaviconInfo`, let `GoogleFaviconFinder`, `DefaultFaviconFinder`, etc implement it, then have a `addFaviconFinder` method, which adds the finder. Then, invoke can iterate over them until one works.

I would also add even more classes. Eg:

- `$pipe`: This seems to be a magic array holding some input and output values. Arrays such as this are difficult to use (especially without proper documentation). I would probably create some kind of class instead, and give it a proper name (such as `FaviconInfo`).
- `favicon_code`: I'm not sure what this is used for, but some kind of class, or at least an array mapping the characters to properly named indices would be nice.
- same goes for `domain_code`.

**Naming**

Many of your variables and function names could be more concrete. For example `$pipe` or `invoke`, `$types`, `$key`, `$value`, `$temp`, `$set`, or `$matches` are very vague.

Comment: I agree is is too big, but keeping for now while troulbeshooting - check rev 3 - I updated some of the names.

Comment: please let me know why you did not up-vote.

Comment: @arc.slate.0 I don't always upvote questions I answer (I do on the other hand upvote pretty much all answer to my questions). If your asking what could be improved about the question, a couple of things come to mind: the title (describe what the code does, not what you want out of a review), the missing description (just a sentence or maybe two on what your code does), don't ask about why something is broken (it seems off-topic to me), make a bit more clear what exactly you want out of a review (what validation do you mean, exactly? how/why do you want to check the integrity?, etc).

Comment: @arc.slate.0 See also [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436) (in addition to the points I mentioned, it also mentions tags). Please also note [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765), I rolled back your edit.